# How to output table column values individually in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
 <?php
    include ('conn_db.php');
     mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot      connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
    /* Fetch first row */
    $sql="SELECT *  FROM `monthly_payment` GROUP BY `card`"; //First row
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    $pays = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $pays[]=$row['card'];
    }

/* Fetch second one */

$sql2="SELECT *  FROM `users`"; // Second row
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

if($result2 === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
$usrs = array();
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$usrs[]=$row2['card'];
}
$newArray = array_diff($usrs, $pays);// To make difference
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

In this code the output is like:

```
Array ( [3] => RN166 [4] => RN100 )
```

Whenever I want to print the output using 'echo', there are error messages appearing. I want to see this output like:

```
RN166,RN100
```

using "echo". So I can fetch all the fields from DB using foreach loop.

*monthly_payment*

```
id  |  card
1   | RN122
2   | DD13
3   | RN155
4   | RN155
```

*users*

```
id  |  card
-----------
1   | RN122
2   | DD13
3   | RN155
4   | RN166
5   | RN100
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
echo implode(',', $newArray);
```

Comment: thanks Mario...this code is now working great...

Answer (score 1):

use implode function this may helpful to you

```
echo implode(',', $newArray);
```